# SQL statement get all forums and subforums?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    | fid | fup | type  | name          |
 ---+-----+-----+--------+--------------+----------
    |  1  |  0  | group | category      |
    |  2  |  1  | forum  | forum_name    |
    |  3  |  1  | forum | forum_name2   |
    |  4  |  2  | sub   | subforum_name |
    |  5  |  2  | sub   | subform_name2 |
    |  6  |  0  | group | category2     |
    |  7  |  6  | forum  | forum_namex   |
    ........
 ---+-----+-----+--------+--------------+----------
```

Can anyone give me a MySQL statement?
to get all forums and subforums' fids attaching to the group，when get a category's fid.

Comment: What's fup's purpose?

Comment: Do you have any constrain to identify forum or subforum. According to your table, try this code can be solve your issue. `SELECT fid from table where name like 'forum_%' or name like 'subform_%';`

Comment: Does your table have only three types called **group,forum and sub**  ?

Comment: thanks.the names don't have the same pattern,with "SELECT * FROM `forum` WHERE fup=1".i can get the forum but don't know how to get the subforums belong to the category

Comment: yes only three types

Comment: please check your type has another field called **form**. Is it mistake ? Update questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query.

```
SELECT f1.name as forums , f2.name as subforums FROM forum f 
LEFT JOIN forum f1 ON f.fid=f1.fup
LEFT JOIN forum f2 ON f1.fid=f2.fup
where f.fup=0 and f.fid=1
```

Comment: @HenRy If this is working for you , mark as correct

Comment: thank you,but not work perfect.i get a subquery sql solve it. SELECT fid,name FROM `forum` where fup=1 or fup IN (SELECT fid FROM `forum` where fup=1)

Comment: I am sorry.I check your codes again,it works perfect.thank you very much.